# SQL Server: Default action for opened transaction in a stored procedure if cancelled from .net code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am executing a stored procedure on my .net code. The stored procedure has begin transaction and it only commits once there is no error, otherwise it will rollback the transaction. If I'm going to cancel the execution of the stored procedure from my .net code, does the transaction will be committed or rolled back?

Comment: What do you mean you are going to cancel the execution?

Comment: If the stored procedure has not yet committed the transaction at the point where .NET cancels the command, then the transaction will be rolled back. If it has already committed, cancelling will leave the already committed transaction alone, unless you've *also* started a transaction from within .NET -- in this case the stored procedure's transaction is a nested transaction that won't successfully commit until the outer transaction commits.

Comment: That helps @JeroenMostert. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is the transaction started with `BEGIN TRAN` in the proc code will remain open after the proc is cancelled by the client. When the connection is closed, it will be returned to the connection pool with the open transaction. The transaction will not get rolled back until the pooled connection is reused or physically closed due to inactivity.

You can (and should) add `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to the stored procedure so that SQL Server will automatically roll back the transaction following an application cancel request or timeout. This is a best practice when one uses explicit transactions in stored procedures to avoid inadvertently leaving transactions open for longer than necessary, or even worse, unwittingly performing other work in the connection with the open transaction.

Don't try to manage transactions on both the client and server. Choose one or the other.